# How to insert elements into an arbitrarily deep nested list of empty lists

Tags: python, list, nested

Into an arbitrarily deeply nested list of empty lists I want to insert elements from a list of lists. Both lists have the same length.

For example, I might want to insert

```
a = [ [1], [2,3], [[4,5]] ]
```

into

```
b =  [ [[ ]], [[[[ ]]]], [ ] ]
```

so that I obtain

```
c =  [ [[1]], [[[[2,3]]]], [ [4,5] ] ].
```

I have tried various things, but am not getting close to a workable solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion:

```
a = [ [1], [2,3], [[4,5]] ]
b =  [ [[ ]], [[[[ ]]]], [ ] ]
def update(j, k):
   return next(k) if not j else [update(i, k) for i in j]

print(update(b, iter(a)))
```

Output:

```
[[[1]], [[[[2, 3]]]], [[4, 5]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

For each sub-list of `b` you can iteratively assign the inner sub-list to the same variable until the sub-list becomes empty, at which point you can copy the corresponding sub-list in `a` to the empty sub-list in-place:

```
for s, l in zip(a, b):
    while l:
        l, =  l
    l[:] = s
```

so that `b` becomes:

```
[[[1]], [[[[2, 3]]]], [[4, 5]]]
```